# Exclude XML directive from XslCompiledTransform.Transform output

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I'm using an `XsltCompiledTransform` to transform some XML into a fragment of HTML (not a complete HTML document, just a DIV that I will include in page generated elsewhere).

I'm doing the transformation as follows:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

XmlReader rawData = BusinessObject.GetXml();
XmlWriter transformedData = XmlWriter.Create(output);

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();

transform.Load("stylesheet.xslt");

transform.Transform(rawData, transformedData);

Response.Write(output.ToString());
```

My problem is that the result of the transform always begins with this XML directive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

How do I prevent this from appearing in my transformed data?

**EDIT:**

I'm telling the XSLT that I don't want it to output an xml declaration with

```
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

but this seems to have no effect on the directive appearing in my output.

Interestingly, both my XML data source and my XSLT transform specify themselves as `UTF-8` not `UTF-16`.

**UPDATE:**
The UTF-16 seems to be appearing because I'm using a string(builder) as an output mechanism. When I change the code to use a `MemoryStream` instead of a `StringBuilder`, my UTF-8 encoding is preserved. I'm guessing this has something to do with the internal workings of the `string` type and how it deals with encoding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use an `XmlWriterSettings` object. Set its properties to omit the XML declaration, and pass it to the constructor of your `XmlWriter`.

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
XmlReader rawData = BusinessObject.GetXml();

XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

using (XmlWriter transformedData = XmlWriter.Create(output, writerSettings))
{
  XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
  transform.Load("stylesheet.xslt");
  transform.Transform(data, transformedData);
  Response.Write(output.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go. It's not an XSLT problem - the declaration is written by `XmlWriter` in the first place, not by `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: But why doesn't the XmlWriter take its settings from the XSLT?

Comment: Because once it's created, it cannot change its settings by design. So once XSLT receives it, it cannot really do anything about it. If you use a `Transform()` overload which takes a `TextWriter` or `Stream`, it will create an `XmlWriter` with correct settings for you.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the insight Pavel.

Comment: Hmm, I used the overload to output directly to memory stream, and still ran into UTF16 encoding. Perhaps its creating a default xml writer to support the stream overload anyway? Rather than worry about it, I just used the code above and all is well :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to add this node to your XSLT:

```
<xsl:output 
    method="html" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

Comment: He's only interested in HTML, so I would do method="html" and perhaps version="somehtmlversion".

Comment: @Andrew - sorry, this doesn't work.
@Gonzalo - yes, that's exactly what I'm doing